# How to parent correctly

Tags: rigging, weight-painting, vertex-weights

I made a sonic model and am now into the rigging process.I separated the mouth eyes, nose, and mouth from the main mesh and planned on parenting all three of them to the head bone so that they would follow the head. For some reason the mouth isn't following the head correctly and whenever I rotate the head bone. There's always a break. You should be able to see the blend file, and if you rotate the head you'll see it doesn't follow the right way.

[image: gap]

[image]

Comment: Hello :). Consider [sharing your .blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), so others can take alook.

Comment: Thank you for that.

Comment: How come after asking that, you never bothered to try to help me??? Its been months...

Comment: Hey :). I just don't know much about rigging. However, if you edit your post (add more tags, use paragraphs), perhaps others will help you. Good luck :).

Comment: Posts should be self explanatory without having to download medium-sized files. I have taken the liberty of adding a screenshot of the gap. Is this the problem you are describing? Also, your tags are completely incorrect. This question is not about rendering. It is about rigging. I have added the correct tags, so the question can actually be found. I know that finding technical terms is very difficult, but you should try to search for weight painting (also in the tags now). How did you create your vertex weights and why do you expect the mouth and face mesh to actually line up?

Comment: Hey, just a quick tip, if you want to understand the process of rigging and how to get rid of artifacts **don't use Rigify**. 

I know it can be tempting always to take the easiest route possible but especially as a learner you should invest some time and effort into understanding Blender's default features before diving into Add-ons. I'd advise you to watch some tutorials on rigging online and redo your rig manually. That might be a good first step to at least understand the source your problems.